# Is 'We are for it' correct usage?

Tags: idiom-requests, popular-refrains, equivalence

If war—or anything, for that matter—was impending, people might say "We are up for it," to hearten the spirits of everyone and to ready them for the coming conflict.

> 1: It looks like it is war.
>
> 2: War it is and we are for it (we are its equals/its people)

it's Arabic for  نحن (أهل)لها.

Are there any similar enthusiastic saying in English?

Answer (score 2):

***[Be for it](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/be-for-it)*** means:

> - (British informal) Be in imminent danger of punishment or other trouble.
>
>   - *We knew it would hurt; we knew we were for it in a big way.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

I think you mean:

We are up to it:

***[Be up to](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+be+up+to)***:

> - To be equal to, or prepared for;
>
>   - *he is up to the business, or the emergency.*

(The Free Dictionary)

You may use ***[face](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/face):***

> - To meet or confront with self-assurance.
>
>   - How can I face your parents when they know that I've let them down?

- Come what may, we are ready to face it!

Comment: "To be for something" can also mean "to be in favour of something".

Comment: OP already knows about "To be up/for it",....he/she wants more examples.

Comment: How would I integrate that into say hardship. If hardship comes, we are .....?

Comment: @user151577 - we are ready  ***to face it***.

Comment: "If hardship comes, we are ready to go all the way". .....meaning right to the end if need be"

Comment: This site needs to somehow create a compilation of trans-atlantic differences.  Because AFAIK, in AmEng, "to be for something" can *only* mean "to be in favor of something."

Comment: @cobaltduck - the idiomatic expression is ***Be fot it***  as said it is British. ***Be for (in favour of) something*** is quite literal.

Comment: @Josh61 given the level of English demonstrated in the question, I think it is safe to say that the asker can reasonably profit from guidance on the use of literal expressions.

Answer (score 1):

***It is war, and we are for it***, has various possible meanings.

It could mean, quite literally that we are ***in favour of it (being war)***.

If, if it implied enthusiasm it would probably be *it is war, and we are **up for it***.

However, idiomatically it can mean something quite different. Indeed, the most likely meaning, in my view, and without knowing more of the context is that it means ***it is war, and we are in for serious punishment***.

***Now you are for it***, has usually meant ***now you are in for serious trouble***.

From reading @Josh61's answer, I gather that this last idiom may be uniquely British.

Comment: What I mean here is we are the boss at it, we can ride it out, come what come may sort of thing. We qualify for it. I just a nice formal way of saying. We are for it. Lost in translation I guess.

Comment: @user151577 Then I would say either *...and we are ready for it*, or *...and we are up for it*. *We are for it* could easily be taken as a lament that misery was on its way.

Comment: @WS2 I'd (US born and bred, but with much more exposure to British idioms than most Americans) never have understood "we are for it" as indicating serious trouble.  To me, it sounds somewhat old fashioned, like something you'd hear in a historical drama.

Comment: @phoog Well I am a bit *historical* myself. It may have gone out of fashion, but as an idiom it has been alive and well during most of my life. *You've been caught in the act, now you are for it*. Or even *...now you're for the high jump*.

Comment: I frequently forget how reliant I am on context to understand idioms like this.  The first time I heard "the beeb" I knew instantly what it meant, but only because we were talking about television.

Answer (score 0):

"It is war and **we'll take the fight to them**."

"It is war; We'll **give as good as we get** if not more".

Comment: What if it wasn't war, let's say hardship was about to beset, how would you say it. 'We are for hardship'?

Comment: "We are very well prepared for the onset of any hardships".

"If hardship comes, we are ready to go all the way". .....meaning right to the end if need be"

Comment: I want a snappy few words that can enthuse an audience. Like bring on hardship and rigour, 'we are for it'. Like we are up those hard times.

Comment: "If hardship comes, we are ready to go all the way"

Answer (score 0):

In recent U.S. history, two expressions of readiness to take action in a dangerous situation have approached the status of idioms: "Bring it on!" and "Let's roll!"

"Bring it on" may have become famous in the first place as the title of a popular movie about competitive cheerleading released in 2000, but it also received strong reinforcement from a speech that George W. Bush gave in 2003, daring anti-U.S. insurgents in Iraq to do their worst, by saying "Bring 'em on."

"Let's roll" got its start from a recording of one of the passengers aboard United Flight 93 just before a group of passengers attempted to overpower the hijackers of that airplane on September 11, 2001.

Leslie Savan, [*Slam Dunks and No-Brainers: Language in Your Life, the Media, Business, Politics, and, Like, Whatever*](https://books.google.com/books?id=IFo_uB66P_MC&pg=PT132&dq=%22war+words+yin+and+yang%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-kp7HjMLKAhUE82MKHcp-BiAQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22war%20words%20yin%20and%20yang%22&f=false) (2005) has an interesting discussion of both of these phrases in a subsection of her book titled "War Words Yin and Yang."